# Why am I getting 'Can't read from server error' with Swagger and OIDC?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openid-connect

I have added OIDC via call to a MITREid server on a different domain to a swagger app. I have set redirect URI to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` When I authorise I am getting:

```
Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate 
access-control-origin settings
```

error.

My web-security-config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${security.activation.status}")
private boolean securityActivationStatus;

@Value("${security.user.name}")
private String builtinUserName;

@Value("${security.user.password}")
private String builtinPassword;

@Autowired
private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;


 */
String[] apiPath = {
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/configuration/ui",
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**"
};
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("securityActivationStatus=" + securityActivationStatus);
    if (!securityActivationStatus)
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

    else {
        http
        .addFilterAfter(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(myFilter(), OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class)
        .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/openid_connect_login"))
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(apiPath).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/v1/**").authenticated();
    }




    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}

@Bean
public OpenIdConnectFilter myFilter() {

    final OpenIdConnectFilter filter = new OpenIdConnectFilter("/openid_connect_login");
    filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    return filter;
}
```

POM includes:

```
<properties>
        <springfox.version>2.7.0</springfox.version>
        <swagger.version>1.5.17</swagger.version>
        <swagger2markup.version>1.3.1</swagger2markup.version>
        <!-- For CheckStyle -->
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
        <spring-security-jwt.version>1.0.9.RELEASE</spring-security-jwt.version>
        <jwks-rsa.version>0.3.0</jwks-rsa.version>
        <mitreid-connect-version>1.3.1</mitreid-connect-version>
    </properties>
```

Form my research it seems this might be to do with CORS. Does that sound like a likely problem or is my code maybe missing something? If it is CORS can you point me in the right direction of how to sort it? I am a complete noob to swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps someone the answer was `/openid_connect_login` was the wrong uri.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the cors :

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
    if (HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name().equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) req).getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It did not fix the problem, same as before.

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myserver:8080/openid-connect-server-webapp/authorize?client_id=myckient&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&state=4gqH2Y' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

Comment: I was not sure what to put for `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Foo, Bar, Baz");`

Comment: @schoon !! i edited my post check it again !! `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check`  just return an **OK response for OPTION request**